# "Conditional" Fields in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor-pages

Im making a ASP NET CORE Razor Pages project and I have the this class

MyObject.cs

```
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Val01 { get; set; }   
public string Val02 { get; set; }
//...
public string Val30 { get; set; }
}
```

And I have 5 different types of "MyObjects" each one have different combinations of properties; for instance, "MyObject_ASD"
use the Id, Name, Val01, Val02, Val05; but "MyObject_QWE" only use Id, Name, Val11, Val13, Val17.

I need to  know what is the best/optimal way to implement a page shows only the fields of the selected "MyObject"

PS

In a MVC approach I use five _Create.cshtml views, like _CreateASD.cshtml, _CreateQWE.cshtml with a switch-case in the 
controller.

```
            switch (type)
        {
            case MyObjectType.QWE:
                return PartialView("_CreateQWE", object);
            case MyObjectType.ASD:
                return PartialView("_CreateASD", object);
            case MyObjectType.ZXC:
                return PartialView("_CreateZXC", object);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, if each object has different properties, they must be different objects. If the objects has many common properties, they must has a mother class. I agree with your approach and each object has your own view. It's just my opinion, but i don't know the context to make sure.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use inheritance class to create multiple similar class.

It's make your code clean and more readable and easy to control.

---

In your case, for example :

Create a base class, and other class inherit this base.

Controller :

```cs
// base class 
public class MyObject
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

// derived class
public class MyObjectA : MyObject
{
    public string Val01 { get; set; }
    public string Val02 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObjectB : MyObject
{
    public string Val03 { get; set; }
    public string Val04 { get; set; }
}
public class MyObjectC : MyObject
{
    public string Val05 { get; set; }
    public string Val06 { get; set; }
}
```

View :

```
switch (type)
{
   case MyObjectA :
      return PartialView("_CreateQWE", MyObjectA );
   case MyObjectB :
      return PartialView("_CreateASD", MyObjectB );
   case MyObjectC :
      return PartialView("_CreateZXC", MyObjectC );
}
```

or even you can create a enums property to distinguish your modals.